# Modal that use data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#id" don't go to their destination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to focus the input field using modal data-target function on button click. It is focusin but a div called `<div class="modal-backdrop in">` is created and modal didn't get close properly.[image] So user can't click anywhere on the site. There seems to be an issue that I cannot find documented and hopefully, someone here can shed some light on it. I want to focus on that input field when user click `Upload Now` button on modal. Here is the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wLp7sszu/11/)

```css
.height500 {
  height:500px;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="height500"><input type="text" name="" class="" id="noimgtakediv" /></div>
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#portfoliomsgmodal" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"> Click to Open Modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="portfoliomsgmodal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">TIP</h3> </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <label>There are twice as much chances of you getting contacted by your customers if you upload something in your portfolio. Upload photos or video or audio links to your profile.</label>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-warning" data-target="#noimgtakediv" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal">Upload Now</button> 
                <input type="submit" id="submitlater" class="btn btn-primary nomargin" value="Remind me later">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `Jquery focus()`

```js
$('#portfoliomsgmodal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $('#noimgtakediv').focus();
})
```

```css
.height500 {
  height:500px;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="height500"><input type="text" name="" class="" id="noimgtakediv" /></div>
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#portfoliomsgmodal" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"> Click to Open Modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="portfoliomsgmodal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">TIP</h3> </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <label>There are twice as much chances of you getting contacted by your customers if you upload something in your portfolio. Upload photos or video or audio links to your profile.</label>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-warning"  data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal">Upload Now</button> 
                <input type="submit" id="submitlater" class="btn btn-primary nomargin" value="Remind me later">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: glad to help you @acmsohail

Answer (score 1):

Check this One

```css
.height500 {
  height:500px;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="height500"><input type="text" name="" class="" id="noimgtakedivnew" /></div>
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#portfoliomsgmodal" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"> Click to Open Modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="portfoliomsgmodal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">TIP</h3> </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <label>There are twice as much chances of you getting contacted by your customers if you upload something in your portfolio. Upload photos or video or audio links to your profile.</label>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="focusontest()">Upload Now</button> 
                <input type="submit" id="submitlater" class="btn btn-primary nomargin" value="Remind me later">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
function focusontest()
{
setTimeout(function(){   $("#noimgtakedivnew").focus() }, 500);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I want to take user to that particular input when user click "Upload Now" button. U just remove the `data-target` It will just close the modal ONLY. I want to use `data-target` and get back to user to that particular input. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Do you want when user click on "Upload Now" button then focus on the textbox?

Comment: Yes exactly :) Please check my code it focus on that particular input but modal didn't close it properly.

Comment: Thanks Karan. @JYoThI already fixed the issue, but I voted for you too. :)